# Sorry, that page does not exist, Error code 34 when getting twitter share count

Tags: twitter, share

I am using the below url for getting the share count for twitter

```
https://cdn.syndication.twitter.com/widgets/tweetbutton/count.json?url=google.com
```

It is working finee before yesterday then sudden its get broken and I am getting below response from twitter when calling above url

```
    "errors": 



{
    "message": "Sorry, that page does not exist",
    "code": ​34
}
```

Then I have also tried below url for getting share count

```
https://cdn.api.twitter.com/1/urls/count.json?url=www.google.com
http://urls.api.twitter.com/1/urls/count.json?url=www.google.com
```

It also result in same error

Please anyone can help me how can I get the proper share count in twitter, And I am not so good in English I apologies for that

Answer (score 2):

Twitter disabled this feature a few days ago that's the reason why it is not working anymore.
You can find more information by reading this [blog post](https://blog.twitter.com/2015/hard-decisions-for-a-sustainable-platform).

Comment: Thanks for answer but is there any alternate way now we can get twitter share count?

Answer (score 0):

Twitter shut down this API, but you can get an alternative at http://opensharecount.com